# Split dataset without sampling in R

Tags: r, dataset

This is my problem. I have a set of one year of meteorological data with hourly observations. I want to split it into days. So I don't want a sampling of it, but simply split it every 24 rows. So I want a new dataset with the length of the days. This is an example of two days of my dataset.

```
Year Mounth Day     date temp humidity wind Hour
1  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     74.0  7.2    0
2  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     74.0  7.2    1
3  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     74.0  7.2    2
4  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -3     73.8  4.6    3
5  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -4     79.6  3.6    4
6  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -4     79.6  4.6    5
7  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -5     85.8  4.1    6
8  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -6     85.7  2.6    7
9  2017      1   1 01/01/17   -4     79.6  3.6    8
10 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     68.6  3.6    9
11 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -1     68.8  7.2   10
12 2017      1   1 01/01/17    0     63.9  7.2   11
13 2017      1   1 01/01/17    1     64.2  6.2   12
14 2017      1   1 01/01/17    2     59.7  4.6   13
15 2017      1   1 01/01/17    1     64.2  4.6   14
16 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -1     68.8  3.6   15
17 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     68.6  3.6   16
18 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -1     74.2  4.1   17
19 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     79.9  5.7   18
20 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -3     86.0  5.7   19
21 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     79.9  7.2   20
22 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -3     86.0  8.2   21
23 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -2     79.9  7.2   22
24 2017      1   1 01/01/17   -1     80.0  7.2   23
25 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     86.3  7.2    0
26 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     86.3  7.7    1
27 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     86.3  7.2    2
28 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     86.3  7.7    3
29 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     92.9  7.7    4
30 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     92.9  7.2    5
31 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     92.9  7.7    6
32 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1    100.0  7.2    7
33 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1    100.0  8.2    8
34 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1    100.0  7.7    9
35 2017      1   2 02/01/17    0     93.0  6.7   10
36 2017      1   2 02/01/17    0    100.0  5.7   11
37 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     93.0  6.2   12
38 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     93.0  4.1   13
39 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     93.0  4.1   14
40 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     93.0  5.1   15
41 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     86.5  5.1   16
42 2017      1   2 02/01/17    1     86.5  4.6   17
43 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     92.9  3.6   18
44 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -3    100.0  3.6   19
45 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -2     92.8  4.1   20
46 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -2     92.8  7.7   21
47 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -2     92.8  6.7   22
48 2017      1   2 02/01/17   -1     92.9  7.2   23
```

this is my code that do not works...

```
 datasplit <- lapply(split(nrow(data), ceiling((1:nrow(data))/24)),           function(i) data[i, ])
```

The result I expect is a new dataset with the dimensions=(2,24,8):

2 is the number of days (this example)

24 is the number of hours

8 is the number of columns

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lapply` family of functions might be overkill here. I think all you need is `split`. Just make sure that the variable you are splitting by, is of type `factor`.

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Year    : int  2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
 $ Mounth  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Day     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ date    : Factor w/ 2 levels "01/01/17","02/01/17": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ temp    : int  -2 -2 -2 -3 -4 -4 -5 -6 -4 -2 ...
 $ humidity: num  74 74 74 73.8 79.6 79.6 85.8 85.7 79.6 68.6 ...
 $ wind    : num  7.2 7.2 7.2 4.6 3.6 4.6 4.1 2.6 3.6 3.6 ...
 $ Hour    : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

Based on my default import, `Day` appears to be of type `int` or integer not a factor. If that's the case for you, then the following should work.

```
    data$Day <- as.factor(data$Day)
   datasplit <- split(data, data$Day)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
str(datasplit)
List of 2
     $ 1:'data.frame':  24 obs. of  8 variables:
      ..$ Year    : int [1:24] 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
      ..$ Mounth  : int [1:24] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      ..$ Day     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      ..$ date    : Factor w/ 2 levels "01/01/17","02/01/17": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      ..$ temp    : int [1:24] -2 -2 -2 -3 -4 -4 -5 -6 -4 -2 ...
      ..$ humidity: num [1:24] 74 74 74 73.8 79.6 79.6 85.8 85.7 79.6 68.6 ...
      ..$ wind    : num [1:24] 7.2 7.2 7.2 4.6 3.6 4.6 4.1 2.6 3.6 3.6 ...
      ..$ Hour    : int [1:24] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
     $ 2:'data.frame':  24 obs. of  8 variables:
      ..$ Year    : int [1:24] 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
      ..$ Mounth  : int [1:24] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      ..$ Day     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
      ..$ date    : Factor w/ 2 levels "01/01/17","02/01/17": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
      ..$ temp    : int [1:24] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
      ..$ humidity: num [1:24] 86.3 86.3 86.3 86.3 92.9 92.9 92.9 100 100 100 ...
      ..$ wind    : num [1:24] 7.2 7.7 7.2 7.7 7.7 7.2 7.7 7.2 8.2 7.7 ...
      ..$ Hour    : int [1:24] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have taken your suggestion and modifies it. In fact in the way you said to me all the first days in the year were the first and so on. But your suggestion let me know where I was wrong.

Comment: Good! Please mark the answer correct if you are satisfied and the question is resolved.

Comment: Ok! Done..If you want to see my other question, that take into account your suggestion, please visit
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740270/nested-loops-in-r-to-calculate-a-mean-day