# Nested loops in R to calculate a mean day

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working on a problem. Try to reproduce a formula in R. I've just done this code in Mathematica, but now I want to reproduce in in R for my students. This is a smart method to calculate a "mean day" in the year, called representative day. This method is described [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hzjvz94oc9fhem/representative%20day.pdf?dl=0).

My part of data is:

```
date    temp    Hour    DayCount
01/01/17    -2  0   1
01/01/17    -2  1   1
01/01/17    -2  2   1
01/01/17    -3  3   1
01/01/17    -4  4   1
01/01/17    -4  5   1
01/01/17    -5  6   1
01/01/17    -6  7   1
01/01/17    -4  8   1
01/01/17    -2  9   1
01/01/17    -1  10  1
01/01/17    0   11  1
01/01/17    1   12  1
01/01/17    2   13  1
01/01/17    1   14  1
01/01/17    -1  15  1
01/01/17    -2  16  1
01/01/17    -1  17  1
01/01/17    -2  18  1
01/01/17    -3  19  1
01/01/17    -2  20  1
01/01/17    -3  21  1
01/01/17    -2  22  1
01/01/17    -1  23  1
02/01/17    -1  0   2
02/01/17    -1  1   2
02/01/17    -1  2   2
02/01/17    -1  3   2
02/01/17    -1  4   2
02/01/17    -1  5   2
02/01/17    -1  6   2
02/01/17    -1  7   2
02/01/17    -1  8   2
02/01/17    -1  9   2
02/01/17    0   10  2
02/01/17    0   11  2
02/01/17    1   12  2
02/01/17    1   13  2
02/01/17    1   14  2
02/01/17    1   15  2
02/01/17    1   16  2
02/01/17    1   17  2
02/01/17    -1  18  2
02/01/17    -3  19  2
02/01/17    -2  20  2
02/01/17    -2  21  2
02/01/17    -2  22  2
02/01/17    -1  23  2
```

So I want to reproduce this formula:
[image: Formula 1]

where `N` is the number of days in the time period (now 2) and every `cki` and `ckj` are the temperatures of the ith day at the kth hour.
What I have is a symmetrical matrix with all zero in the diagonal.
Then I have to sum all the row 
[image: Formula 2]

Here is my code:

```
 data$DayCount <- as.factor(data$DayCount)
 datasplit <- split(data, data$DayCount) #Split my data for each day
 distance=matrix() #Create an empty matrix

 for (k in 1:24) {
 for (i in 1:2) {
   for (j in 1:2) {


distance[i,j]= ((datasplit[[i]][k,2]-datasplit[[j]][k,2])^2)
sum=sum(distance)
            }
   }
 }
```

Any suggestions? I know that you are able to do it.. Help me please!

Comment: Are you attempting to create a matrix of euclidean distances of the hourly temperatures between two days?

Comment: Yes it is the distance between days, than if you minimize this distance you can find the more representative day in one year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's create a dataframe object so we can manipulate our data easily:

```
df <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors = TRUE, text = 'date, temp, Hour, DayCount
01/01/17, -2, 0 , 1
01/01/17, -2, 1 , 1
01/01/17, -2, 2 , 1
01/01/17, -3, 3 , 1
01/01/17, -4, 4 , 1
01/01/17, -4, 5 , 1
01/01/17, -5, 6 , 1
01/01/17, -6, 7 , 1
01/01/17, -4, 8 , 1
01/01/17, -2, 9 , 1
01/01/17, -1, 10, 1
01/01/17, 0 , 11, 1
01/01/17, 1 , 12, 1
01/01/17, 2 , 13, 1
01/01/17, 1 , 14, 1
01/01/17, -1, 15, 1
01/01/17, -2, 16, 1
01/01/17, -1, 17, 1
01/01/17, -2, 18, 1
01/01/17, -3, 19, 1
01/01/17, -2, 20, 1
01/01/17, -3, 21, 1
01/01/17, -2, 22, 1
01/01/17, -1, 23, 1
02/01/17, -1, 0 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 1 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 2 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 3 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 4 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 5 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 6 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 7 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 8 , 2
02/01/17, -1, 9 , 2
02/01/17, 0 , 10, 2
02/01/17, 0 , 11, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 12, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 13, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 14, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 15, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 16, 2
02/01/17, 1 , 17, 2
02/01/17, -1, 18, 2
02/01/17, -3, 19, 2
02/01/17, -2, 20, 2
02/01/17, -2, 21, 2
02/01/17, -2, 22, 2
02/01/17, -1, 23, 2')
```

Now let's try to follow your indications, I'm not attempting to achieve this the most optimal way but to try to stick to your original idea as much as possible, so I'll use a couple of nested loops:

```
# get the different days
days <- levels(df$date)
# create the A matrix, empty
A <- matrix(nrow = length(days), ncol = length(days))
# iterate
for(i in 1:length(days)) {
  for(j in 1:length(days)) {
    # get all the temperatures available for each day
    ci <- df[df$date == days[i],]$temp
    cj <- df[df$date == days[j],]$temp
    # update the A matrix
    A[i, j] <- sum((ci - cj)^2)
  }
}
# finally the last sum
Aj <- unlist(lapply(1:length(days), function(i) sum(A[i, ])))
```

The results are:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   97
[2,]   97    0

> Aj
[1] 97 97
```

This should work for any number of days and for as many temperature measurements per day as you want (not necessarily 24).